# Creating a user to read all this data in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an account which can read all the data in the each of the document. How it is currently set up is that each authenticated can only read his/her data. I want this one specific user to be able to see everyone data:

This is what I am trying to do to right a rule where if a specific user logs in he can read and write to all documents:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
   match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  match /users/{uid}/jobs/{document=**}{
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
          }
      match /users/{uid}/entries/{document=**}{
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
          }
      
      if (uid == utettoeet){
      allow read, write;
      } 
    }
  }
```

Please be advised I just starting firebase and flutter.

```
Widget _buildContents(BuildContext context) {
final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);
return StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
  stream: database.jobsStream(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
      snapshot: snapshot,
      itemBuilder: (context, job) => Dismissible(
        key: Key('job-${job.id}'),
        background: Container(color: Colors.red),
        direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
        onDismissed: (direction) => _delete(context, job),
        child: JobListTitle(
          job: job,
          onTap: () => JobEntriesPage.show(context, job),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Specifically: there is no reason to post the rules as a screenshot. It typically also helps if you describe what the problem is, rather then just the use-case you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] With the following code, the authenticated user with the uid `utettoeet` is allowed to read and write any document in any collection and any user authenticated can read and write its own documents but NOT documents of other users:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == "utettoeet";
    }
    match /users/{uid}/{collection}/{document=**}{
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work I still can only read data which was create by utettoeet and not by other users do you think it can be due to my code in flutter itself and not due to the 
cloud firestore rule

Comment: Thanks for the help but I really think it is something with my flutter code itself now.

Comment: I am following a tutorial so I thought it was the rule in firestore which prevents users from reading other users data but I no longer am sure how flutter and firebase works hand in hand.

Comment: do you think i may hv to use an if statement and if a specific user login navigator to a different route which prints all documents instead of navigatoring to my current route which seems to only print the data create by the user

Comment: is not really an error is more just looking for guidance on how to go about the problem